# Asp.Net Core 2.1: TreeView and TreeNode

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

In .Net framework 4.7, TreeView and TreeNode are available in System.Web.UI.WebControls namespace. But that namespace is not implemented in .Net core 2.1. Is there a work around for TreeView and TreeNode in asp.net core?

Comment: ASP.NET Web Form only works on Full .NET Framework. Could you elaborate more?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, TreeView and TreeNode are available from .Net Core 3.0. Have a look at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview?view=netcore-3.0). This will not be available for 2.x or 1.x versions of .Net Core

Answer (score 0):

.Net Core code was re-engineered to work under Mac, Unix-Based OS's and Windows, therefore Windows specific features, such as TreeView and TreeNode were removed from the .Net Core libraries for the sake of portability. (May be they will be included in the future)

If you still want to use them, they are still available under the latest [.Net FrameWork](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview?view=netframework-4.7.2)